# How to generate mysql query with this json data?

Tags: php, json

This is the sample data receiving to the php script

```
[{"id":1,"due_date":"2011-09-03","due_amount":"48279.00","wo_interest":"45980.00"},
 {"id":2,"due_date":"2011-10-03","due_amount":"48279.00","wo_interest":"45980.00"}]
```

and the table fields are in this order

```
loan_no,i_id,due_date,installment,due_amount,wo_interest
```

below the order which matching to json data im receiving.

```
i_id,due_date,due_amount,wo_interest
```

how to add loan_no and installment to this and make a mysql query with it?

Comment: Order doesn't matter - neither in JSON objects nor in column names in SQL queries.

Comment: Decode from JSON to the array, sort the array, add what's needed, make loop and each time execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through the following steps:

- Make an array out of the JSON data, any PHP JSON decoder can do that.
- Merge this array with the values you also want to set like `$res = array_merge($json_array, array( 'loan_no' => 12);`
- Create the MYSQL Query INSERT with the $res array.

Order doesn't matter for the MYSQL INSERT.

Comment: Thanks a lot. didn't know about the order is doesn't matter in insert

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = json_decode( $sample_data_recieving );
foreach ( $array as $row ){
  $row['loan_no'] = 'SOMETHING_YOU_WANT';
  $row['installment'] = 'SOMETHING_YOU_WANT';
  mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO tbl (i_id,due_date,due_amount,wo_interest,loan_no,installment)
    VALUES ('" . implode( "','", $row ) . "')" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to

```
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

loop through it, write your query, the order does not matter in this case